How do you cure diseases?
A.k.a. How do you undo a Slaad infection now?
In the 2014 rules there were multiple ways to cure diseases using magic: the lesser restoration, heroes' feast, raise dead, resurrection, and true resurrection spells all did it, the paladin's Lay on Hands did it, and the transmutation school wizard's philosopher's stone could do it.
Under the new 2024 rules, the only one of those that remains is the last, because the Transmuter is not one of the new Wizard classes, so you can continue to use the legacy content, for the time being.
Neither  lesser restoration, heroes' feast, raise dead, resurrection, nor the paladin's Lay on Hands now can cure disease, and  true resurrection now can only cure magical diseases, not natural ones. There also is no new cure disease, or remove disease spell, and the medicine skill still gives as examples of what it can do

Diagnose an illness, or determine what killed the recently slain

So, outside of using legacy content or wish, is there any way to cure diseases in the new 5e? As the Slaad tadpole is not described as a magical disease, is there any way to get rid of it during the months it gestates in your chest?

The comment discussion sorrounding this has been moved to chat; feel free to continue it there.

Disease is legacy
Mechanically, disease has been removed from the 2024 PHB. There is no mention of "disease" in any spell effects, creature stat blocks, or rules glossary definitions. Detect Poison and Disease doesn't even detect diseases, anymore.

For the duration, you sense the location of poisons, poisonous or venomous creatures, and magical contagions within 30 feet of yourself. You sense the kind of poison, creature, or contagion in each case.

Update Oct 29, 2024
Most of Chapter 15 has been moved to the 2024 DMG. Disease has indeed been removed from the new system, which instead refers to magical contagions. The new system handles poisons, contagions, and mental stress differently.

Contagion is a much better term, honestly. Until I read some questions on this site, I had no idea that people were interpreting remove disease to be about anything other than infectious diseases, since that was what I had always assumed it to refer to: there were lots of monsters that transmitted infections, but never any discussion of Parkinson's disease or whatever. But apparently that confusion has been widespread, so contagion is a better choice. I am very skeptical about removing means of curing non-magical contagion, though.

Ya, it doesn't matter what you call it. What it does, and how you remove it, matter. The rules seem to need each contagion to describe its own cure.

As much as I want to agree that disease is a legacy, until they release the new books to actually make it so it still very much exists. Everything is meant to be backwards compatible after all.

It is backwards compatible whenever the disease mechanics are removed. Legacy problems require legacy solutions.

I agree it is likely to be removed, but until it actually is I don't think we can claim it as legacy. For now it is just a gap in the rules, and since the rules have forever been full of gaps I don't have 100% faith that it will be fixed in the way we expect.

nonymous @SeriousBri Just in case it's interesting for the answer, according to the video New Dungeon Master's Toolbox | 2024 Dungeon Master's Guide (around 4:57), curses and magical contagions are still a thing. But yes, diseases are wrapped up in the Poisoned condition now.

@Tarod I kinda knew that was coming, if the reworked monster manual updates the salad mechanic then this probably becomes an accept worthy answer.

It doesn't seem like a legacy thing though. Sure, they renamed them from "disease" to "magical contagion". But those old diseases could be cured by Lay on Hands and various spells, Paladins and Monks of sufficient level were immune to them, etc. Now it seems like disease is still a thing, it just has a new name, and no magical means of curing it (unless specified in the contagion's description, e.g. Sight Rot being fixable with Heal or Lesser Restoration). Seems odd to scrub the PHB of this so thoroughly that it nerfs existing class abilities as a side-effect...

@Tarod: Based on what I saw in the PHB, I was expecting the Poisoned to handle the baseline effects of magical contagions as you said (with additional effects lasting as long as the target remained poisoned, so Lay on Hands and Lesser Restoration would work as before without needing to mention disease), but it looks like they took a hard left in the DMG and now there is no consistency on this at all; players can get diseasesmagical contagions, but they have no clue (unless they knew the 2014 edition) that stuff like Lesser Restoration might help.

@ShadowRanger yeah, totally agree. This is something DMs should explain to players since it's not in their book. It would nice to update the answer with this detail.

@Tarod - I think that it was done somewhat clumsily (but what has not been in Dungeons and Dragons?) I guess they wanted to head off discussions about player actions like "I use remove disease to cure autism," reasonably enough. A good way of doing that might have been renaming it to remove contagion and specifying that it was about, well, contagions, not anything that someone might see as possibly putting someone ill at ease, as it were.

But instead they cut the relatively uncontroversial curing of transmissible illnesses, but kept in the spells that can cure things like deafness or limb loss, which are much more controversial issues in real life. Not that I think that keeping those is a totally indefensible choice—e.g. while they are controversial, things like cochlear implants do exist in real life, and discussion of similar ideas in games need not be verboten, if handled carefully (e.g. without a moral slant toward being "able-bodied"). But the choice seems a little haphazard nonetheless.
